# Responsive containers with shapes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I am trying to create this layout:
[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV4kZ.jpg)

I need to create 3 containers and each container will have an image as a background. Tried to do it with SVG, but it's not an option, because in future images will be changed via CMS, so I need a shape, that images can fill in. Also tried to play with the border, so I can create a shape, but it's also not working the way it looks on the image above. Is there an easier way to achieve this? Let's say using bootstrap classes?

Comment: will it be also contents over this image, and if yes how much complex will it be ?

Comment: Only one <h2> in each image

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways 1)using bootstrap classes 2)using @media and for showing proper image according to div size you can use .className{background-size:contain;background-repeat:no-repeat}

Answer (score 0):

You may use flex, transform and pseudo to hold backgrounds:
    /* http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vGvRPZ */

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body > div {
  position:relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  width: 160%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: -30%;
}
div div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-left: solid;
  flex: 4;
  position: relative;
}
div div h2 {
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: turquoise;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  transform: skew(30deg);
}
div div:nth-child(1) h2 {
  padding-left: 50%;
}
div div:nth-child(3) h2 {
  padding-right: 50%;
}
div div:before {
  transform: skew(30deg);
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: url(http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/grungy_background-t2.jpg ) center tomato;
  background-size: 100vw auto;
}
div div:nth-child(2):before {
  background: url(http://www.intrawallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-backgrounds-8656-8993-hd-wallpapers_js7gwWA.jpg) center right gray;
  background-size: 100vw auto;
}
div div:nth-child(3):before {
  background: url(https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/dark_background_colorful_paint_47176_300x188.jpg) center right turquoise;
  background-size: 100vw auto;
}
div div:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 2.5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <h2>title 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>title 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>title 1</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! :)