# Putting a background image inside a shape with pseudo-elements

Tags: html, css, background-image, pseudo-element

I have a slanted div and I was wondering how I could get an image within the div that would fill it entirely. For example, it is a rectangle but there is a triangle added to each end to create the "slanted" part of the shape. I would like separate pictures for each div (so to fill the entire purple space), so being able to have different. Thanks for your help in advance.

```css
/*1st set*/
.rrcontainer {
    padding-bottom: 265px;
}
.rr h2{
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3vw;
    text-align: center;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
}
.rr > div {
  text-align: center;
}

.rr {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  background: purple;
}
.rr.rr-left {
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  width: 55%;
}
.rr.rr-right {
  z-index: 2;
  float: right;
  width: 44%;
}

.rr:after,
.rr:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.rr-left:after {
  right: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid purple;
  border-bottom: 250px solid white;
}

.rr-right:before {
  left: -100px;
  border-right: 100px solid purple;
  border-top: 250px solid transparent;
}

.rr-left > div {
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.rr-right > div {
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.rr:hover {
  background: pink;
}

.rr-left:hover:after {
  border-left-color: pink;
}

.rr-right:hover:before {
  border-right-color: pink;
}

/*2nd set*/
.llcontainer {
    padding-bottom: 265px;
}

.ll h2{
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3vw;
    text-align: center;
     position: relative;

  text-align: center;
}
}
.ll > div {
  text-align: center;
}

.ll {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  background: purple;
}
.ll.ll-left {
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  width: 55%;
}
.ll.ll-right {
  z-index: 2;
  float: right;
  width: 44%;
}

.ll:after,
.ll:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.ll-left:after {
  right: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid purple;
  border-bottom: 250px solid white;
}

.ll-right:before {
  left: -100px;
  border-right: 100px solid purple;
  border-top: 250px solid transparent;
}

.ll-left > div {
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.ll-right > div {
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.ll:hover {
  background: pink;
}

.ll-left:hover:after {
  border-left-color: pink;
}

.ll-right:hover:before {
  border-right-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="rrcontainer">
 <div class="rr rr-left">
 <div>
  <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="rr rr-right">
 <div>
        <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--     ----------------------------   -->
<div class="llcontainer">
<div class="ll ll-left">
 <div>
  <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="ll ll-right">
 <div>
        <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You should consider changing your strategy by using `clip-path` or svg to make this shave with `background-image`. (Actually there is one way, I will leave it in answers)

Comment: Yeap, the answer by DSCH is what I meant to do. If that's not what you wanted to do consider what I said above.

Comment: transform set and then reset the opposite could do it https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zdJbxx ,  mix-blend-mode can also be an hint https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JRdEVO  clip-path seems the best somehow https://codepen.io/rrenula/pen/LzLXYJ

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37050516/responsive-containers-with-shapes/37051628#37051628 (skew method) add margin and text to check it out. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bYOXPj  feel free to respond too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only did left one. Notice I added a background image to the "main" div element(`<div class="rr rr-left">`) and for the triangle part instead of the color purple I used `transparent`. Hopefully it's what you needed.

```css
/*1st set*/
.rrcontainer {
    padding-bottom: 265px;
}
.rr h2{
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3vw;
    text-align: center;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
}
.rr > div {
  text-align: center;
}

.rr {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  background: purple;
}
.rr.rr-left {
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  width: 55%;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
}
.rr.rr-right {
  z-index: 2;
  float: right;
  width: 44%;
}

.rr:after,
.rr:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.rr-left:after {
  right: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 250px solid white;
}

.rr-right:before {
  left: -100px;
  border-right: 100px solid purple;
  border-top: 250px solid transparent;
}

.rr-left > div {
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.rr-right > div {
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.rr:hover {
  background: pink;
}

.rr-left:hover:after {
  border-left-color: pink;
}

.rr-right:hover:before {
  border-right-color: pink;
}

/*2nd set*/
.llcontainer {
    padding-bottom: 265px;
}

.ll h2{
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3vw;
    text-align: center;
     position: relative;

  text-align: center;
}
}
.ll > div {
  text-align: center;
}

.ll {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  background: purple;
}
.ll.ll-left {
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  width: 55%;
}
.ll.ll-right {
  z-index: 2;
  float: right;
  width: 44%;
}

.ll:after,
.ll:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.ll-left:after {
  right: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid purple;
  border-bottom: 250px solid white;
}

.ll-right:before {
  left: -100px;
  border-right: 100px solid purple;
  border-top: 250px solid transparent;
}

.ll-left > div {
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.ll-right > div {
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.ll:hover {
  background: pink;
}

.ll-left:hover:after {
  border-left-color: pink;
}

.ll-right:hover:before {
  border-right-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="rrcontainer">
 <div class="rr rr-left">
 <div>
  <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="rr rr-right">
 <div>
        <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--     ----------------------------   -->
<div class="llcontainer">
<div class="ll ll-left">
 <div>
  <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="ll ll-right">
 <div>
        <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. But the issue is, I'm going to have multiple rows of these two divs, and I want all different pictures. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Is your number of rows may vary? Any ways, you can have an array of images paths, and then select all `.rr-left` and assign the background image of each from the array. `document.getElementsByClass('rr-left`) might help.

Comment: Would you be able to show this in the code example above?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to reflect what you did on the left side with the right side jsfiddle.net/ktxjLh9n

Comment: You are right, I didn't expect it to be trickier for the other side. Maybe you can creating the triangular border to the div it self? Or maybe set the background to the before and it might "continue" to the div it self? Please let me know if you were able to solve it. Good luck!